# Can't install microsoft office as playonlinux doesn't find cdrom

Tags: mount, wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I'm a bit of a newbie to this. 
I downloaded playonlinux in order to install my microsoft office 2007 cd on ubuntu 14.04.
The issue is that it doesn't seem able to select it as it says unable to find the cd rom. The CD rom is labelled 20061111_210213.
If you could guide me through mounting the CD rom or whatever else could be the problem that would be great.
Thanks,
Christina

Comment: the labell you supplied, suggest that your office CD is a copy of a CD. The installer is looking for a CD labeled something like MS OFFICE. try burning a disk from an iso that can be downloaded from microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Try to burn an image dvd from an .iso file of your office 2007, I did with the enterprise version. It worked for me.